# Material Preview jagged surfaces

Tags: 3d-view

the surfaces in Viewport Shading/Material Preview are jagged or spotted. I remade the model, but after a while it happened again. The attached image shows the object with next to it a cube that was just dropped, with no material.
In Render mode, the surfaces are fine
I'll appreciate any help. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Looks possibly GPU related - what kind of GPU do you have? - When was the last time you updated your drivers?

Comment: Are you using Alpha Blend in the material settings?

Comment: It's a MacBook Pro with a M1 chip
8-core CPU
8-core GPU
16-core Neural Engine

Comment: the same happens on an older MacBook

Comment: and I'm not using Alpha Blend

Comment: What are you Clip start and End values in viewport?

Comment: Hello MikoCG, the Clip Start was ridiculously low (0.001 mm). Once back to 1 mm everything looked fine. Solved, thanks a lot